# Images do not display, when image path is returned as a String, which includes a variable

Tags: php

I am having problems displaying images which have been queried from the database. The array from the query result is looped through and the image name is extracted, then passed to a variable which also contains the image path. However when the variable is included in the output, a torn image icon is displayed (no image).

Code:

```
public function loadImages($item) {
  $type = $item;
  $conn = $this->create_connection('read');
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE catagory='$type'";     
  $result = $conn->query($sql)or die(mysql_error());    
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $path = '../images/thumbs/'.$row['image_path'];
     //var_dump($path);
     echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/'.$path.'"/></li>';
  }
```

When I `var_dump` `$path`, it displays the correct file path: `string(28) "../images/thumbs/image1.jpeg"`, with a further seven items, so I am not losing data. I can confirm the path is correct, when I echo the full path and image name, the image displays correctly.

```
echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/image1.jpg"/></li>';
```

Also I have tried removing the `$path` variable and applying `$row` directly:

```
echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/'.$row['image_path'].'"/></li>';
```

I thought the problem was with joining the two strings, so I tried replacing the image variable with `$full_path`, which also did not work:

```
 $full_path = $path . $row['image_path'];
```

`$row` is correct because when I do a `var-dump` for `$row['image_path']` I get the following:

```
string(11) "image1.jpeg" string(11) "image2.jpeg" string(11) .....
```

I previously had the full image path held within the database, when the full image path was used, the images displayed correctly.  I later decided only to store the image name in the database, as the path could change in the future, so the design change created this problem.

Comment: What is the `img` tag that's actually emitted to the browser?  How does it different from the `img` tag that you manually echoed which worked?

Comment: the only difference I can see is adding the varible to the string I don't think I am using the correct syntax?? ../images/thumbs/image1.jpg (manual) ../images/thumbs/'.$path.' (adding varible)

Comment: Right, but what is the result of the string concatenation?  If the images are known to be available and the browser isn't rendering them then the `img` tag has a problem.  Don't just look at the broken image, look at the HTML source of the page and compare the `img` tag with what you think it should be.  That will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I've done a stupid thing been working on this too long today! The file extension is incorrect in my database (jpeg), should be (jpg). Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $path = '../images/thumbs/'.$row['image_path'];
     //var_dump($path);
     echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/'.$path.'"/></li>';
}
```

$path already contains "../images/thumbs/", but you add it again when echoing the line.

Comment: thanks, yes I originally just added $row['image_path] to $path and then echo out echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/'.$path.'"/></li>'; - but i have tried many different ways to get this to work, what would you suggest would be the best approach?

Comment: I've done a stupid thing been working on this too long today! The file extension is incorrect in my database (jpeg), should be (jpg). Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You have the path twice on your echo.

Your code should be like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $path = '../images/thumbs/'.$row['image_path'];
    //var_dump($path);
    echo '<li><img src="$path"/></li>';
}
```

If it doesn't work, try to copy that `var_dump` result and paste in your browser to check if the path is right.

Comment: ok I have added the path and file name to path: $path = '../images/thumbs/'.$row['image_path']; and then i have echo this out: echo '<li><img src="'.$path.'"/></li>'; images still do not display??? var dump of $path produces correct path as used before: string(28) "../images/thumbs/image2.jpeg"

Comment: path is correct if i comment it out and replace with echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/image1.jpg"/></li>'; the image displays correctly

Comment: does the image shows up when you paste the path on your browser address?

Comment: I've done a stupid thing been working on this too long today! The file extension is incorrect in my database (jpeg), should be (jpg). Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Heh, that happens! I told you to check the path just because I did it a few times already. :p

Answer (score 1):

`../images/thumbs/` is being echoed twice. Try this:

```
echo '<li><img src="'.$path.'"/></li>';
```

Comment: ok I have added the path and file name to path: $path = '../images/thumbs/'.$row['image_path']; and then i have echo this out: echo '<li><img src="'.$path.'"/></li>'; images still do not display???

Comment: path is correct if i comment it out and replace with echo '<li><img src="../images/thumbs/image1.jpg"/></li>'; the image displays correctly

Comment: I've done a stupid thing been working on this too long today! The file extension is incorrect in my database (jpeg), should be (jpg). Thanks for all your help!!